How do I turn on Auto Scheduling for the Microsoft Project Application when a new project is created or when I open an existing project?
I'm trying to turn NewTasksStartOn for Microsoft Project on the event of a New Project or Existing Project, but am getting the error (Public member 'NewTasksStartOn' on type 'ProjectClass' not found.  My goal is when a user opens or creates a new Microsoft project plan all new tasks will have schedule mode of "Auto Scheduled".
enter image description here
I'm expecting Auto Scheduling to be turned on for the Microsoft Project application.
